# how to copy back button action to another button

Tags: android, back, onbackpressed

I have a button in which I want to have the same **feature of the usual BACK button**. But just calling the **finish() is not doing the required**.

I tried calling **onBackPressed()** but it needs to create a separate method. Any solution?

```
t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Intent i1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainView.class);
            startActivity(i1); */
            //finish();

            this.onBackPressed() ;

        }


    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it needs to create a separate method"?

Comment: Error Msg: The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener

Comment: Yes, that is because your `this` is the one from the OnClickListener, not the one from your Activity or Fragment. Save the context and use it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `this.onBackPressed();` implies that your are calling a method of `OnClickListener`, which does not exists. Instead call it like this:

```
Your_Activity_Name.this.onBackPressed();
```

Where Your_Activity_Name is the name of your activity.

Answer (score 5):

When you type `this.onBackPressed()` *this* represents `OnClickListener` object, and not your activity.

Try with

```
YourActivityName.this.onBackPressed()
```

or just

```
onBackPressed()
```

In the end you have something like this:

```
t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        YourActivityName.this.onBackPressed();

        // onBackPressed();
        // will do the same
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks  YourActivityName.this.onBackPressed() works.

Comment: @SomnathPal And yet you accepted same answer as mine, that came after mine. :D

Comment: @dmestrovic sorry to bother but your answer came few secs after my answer :) please check the time against questions..

Comment: @AsifMujteba nope. now it says mine was 13 minutes ago, and yours 12. :D (try sorting by oldest. :P )

Comment: @AsifMujteba We wrote basically at the same time. Like you said - few seconds. :D But in the end, I got upvotes, you got accepted answer, so we're good. :D